# Is the index.html file enough to securely disable indexing?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, indexing, webserver

I have an apache2 webserver running. For some directories, I want indexing (listing of the directory content) and for other directories, I do not want indexing.

Is an empty index.html file enough to securely disable indexing?
I know that having a .htaccess file is more "elegant", but is it also better (i.e., more secure) than just an empty index.html file?
Is there any way for third parties (e.g., hackers), to still list the directory content despite having a index.html file or a .htaccess file with "Options -Indexes"?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything inherently insecure about the method you describe. However, this isn't the proper way to prevent directory browsing. It is easy to forget to add an empty `index.html` or `index.php` file to directories especially if you are managing tens of directories.

You should instead configure your web server appropriately to turn  off directory indexing.

This can be done by removing the `Indexes` directive from the `Options` line in `httpd.conf`. If you need to list directory contents for special directories, you can overwrite it in individual directories using the `.htaccess` file.

([source](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37126/how-secure-is-using-a-blank-index-html-index-php))